# How do I set the action of Elasticsearch Output in Logstash pipeline from field in log?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

My Elasticsearch ETL stack takes JSON objects from files using Filebeat and passes them through Logstash to Elasticsearch.  I want to pass an action property in my JSON object that designates either "update" or "delete as the action I want to perform against the document in the index.  My current config has the action hardwired to "update" and will do upserts just fine.

**JSON Sample**

```
{ "key":123,"index_name":"companies","action":"update"}
{ "key":123,"index_name":"companies","action":"delete"}
```

**Current Pipeline.conf**

```
input { 
    beats {
        id => "filebeat-input"
        port => 5044
        codec => "json"
        include_codec_tag => false
    }
} 
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
      id => "elasticsearch-output"
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      document_id => "%{key}"
      index => "%{[@metadata][index_name]}"
      action => "update"
      doc_as_upsert => true
      manage_template => false
    }
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
      id => "elasticsearch-output"
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      document_id => "%{key}"
      index => "%{[@metadata][index_name]}"
      action => "%{action}"
      doc_as_upsert => true
      manage_template => false
    }
}
```

However, if the document doesn't exist, it is not doing an update as expected and it logging an **document_missing_exception** error:

> [2019-08-21T15:21:28,879][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
>   Could not index event to Elasticsearch.
>   {:status=>404, :action=>["update",
>   {:_id=>"123", :_index=>"companies", :_type=>"_doc",
>   :routing=>nil, :retry_on_conflict=>1}, #],
>   :response=>{"update"=>{"_index"=>"companies", "_type"=>"_doc",
>   "_id"=>"123", "status"=>404,
>   "error"=>{"type"=>"document_missing_exception",
>   "reason"=>"[_doc][123]: document missing",
>   "index_uuid"=>"uU9oXFtZSXGodoh70YG3Ng", "shard"=>"0",
>   "index"=>"companies"}}}}

Comment: This happens when you only have update actions in your files or you have both update and delete? Logstash pipelines are parallelized and run per default with a worker per cpu core, could be that an update and a delete are running at the same time.

Comment: @leandrojmp I am only doing an `update` or a `delete` at one time.  My JSON example was just to show them side by side, I don't actually do both at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a conditional in the output part? `if [action] = "delete" {` ES output with delete `} else {` ES output with update `}`.

Comment: @baudsp thanks for the suggestion.  I discovered that that does in fact work prior to posting.  I just don't understand why the above solution does not work.